# Font Awesome from Nuget package and reference from BundleConfig.cs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, nuget-package

I Installed the FontAwesome from NuGet manager console in VS2015 v4.7.0. This placed two files (font-awesome.css/font-awesome.min.css) in ~/Content folder  and fonts folder under ~/fonts. When i opened font-awesome.css, this looks correct.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.7.0') 
  format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2? 
  v=4.7.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff? 
  v=4.7.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf? 
  v=4.7.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg? 
  v=4.7.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

i verified that the reference paths were correct

I included this line of code in BundleConfig.cs to reference this library in the project

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(                    
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css",
                      "~/Content/StickyFooter.css",
                      "~/Content/font-awesome.css"
                      ));
```

Referenced the bundle file like this in _Layout.cshtml page.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
```

This line of code is only showing square box.

```
<span class="input-group-prepend"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-down"></i></span> 

Or 
<span class="input-group-prepend"><i class="fa-angle-double-down"></i></span>
```

Please suggest what am i missing.

Comment: please post the relevant part of your `BundleConfig.cs` (the entire bundle which includes the font awesome css). Also please post where youre including this bundle on a page. also make sure youve cleared the browser cache

Comment: I updated the original post to include the details you asked. Also i referenced the class the other way also. Please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes you need to use are `fa fa-angle-double-down` as opposed to the 2 attempts you listed: `fas fa-angle-double-down` and `fa-angle-double-down`

```
<span class="input-group-prepend"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></span>
```

Note that the `fa` prefix was deprecated in version 5 and replaced with `fas`, `fal`, `far`, and `fab` which I'm sure is why the documentation you're looking at saids `fas`. However, the most recent version of FontAwesome on Nuget is v4.7 so you should be using the older `fa` prefix.

You can find the FontAwesome 4.7 documentation and icon list [here](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/)

Comment: That worked, thank you :) What should we relay on than? i looked at this url https://fontawesome.com/icons/angle-double-down?style=solid and the local font-awesome.css file itself to look for the class name, so are my variations.

Comment: @Cindy check my edited answer. I included a link to the v4.7 documentation that will reflect the classnames you need